# SharePoint: Single Sign On not working for data view web part

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, dataviewwebpart

I'm working with data view web part in SharePoint 2013. For authentication I've to use Single Sign On. I've created one target application ID in Secure Store service. This ID is working fine for BCS. When I'm trying to authenticate data view web part, it's failing.

I've followed blog also. I'm configuring similarly, yet it's failing.
Link: [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2007/08/27/an-introduction-to-single-sign-on-sso-with-data-views.aspx)

A quick help will be appreciated.

Regards,
Vikrant

Comment: What do you mean with "failing"? What error do you get? Please check the ULS log / Event viewer for detailed error. The link from MSDN is by the way something different, they are using the current user's credentials there, requiring double hop => Kerberos. You mention you have a target application ID, meaning that the data retrieval runs under a managed account, not under current user account...

Comment: @Boland, Double hop issue is taken care of by Secure Store service in SharePoint2013. Error while connecting: The server returned a non-specific error when trying to get data from the data source.

Comment: @Boland, My requirement is to use Single Sign On for dataview web part. I tried above blog to use one. It fails with mention error, yet it's working for BCS.

Comment: No, double hop is not taken care of by Secure Store. The Secure Store uses ONE managed account to connect to the data store, not the current user's credentials... Double hop means that the current user's credentials are passed to the data store.

Comment: See this post, perhaps a solution. It's an authentication issue. http://www.cleverworkarounds.com/2013/10/20/another-cause-of-the-server-returned-a-non-specific-error-when-trying-to-get-the-data-view-from-the-data-source/ Or, some other hit: https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=The+server+returned+a+non-specific+error+when+trying+to+get+data+from+the+data+source.&oq=The+server+returned+a+non-specific+error+when+trying+to+get+data+from+the+data+source.&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l3.184j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I think this was addressed in MOSS itself. check here, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2007/08/27/an-introduction-to-single-sign-on-sso-with-data-views.aspx

Comment: Yeah, using Individual Setting in Secure Store Service you could accomplish SSO, but still they have to enter their credentials again when the resource is opened for the first time.